# Codeigniter-login with session

Tags: codeigniter, session-storage

i am trying to do a login with sessions but it doesn't seem to be working because when i log in the session data on the view is not being displayed. once logged in it should read something like: 'Welcome Jon' but it doesn't. What could be the issue

**controller fn**

```
function login_user()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {

        $data = $this->Model_students->fetchUserData();

            if(!empty($data))
            {
                var_dump($data);
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) :
                    $user_id = $value->id;
                    $firstname = $value->firstname;
                    $lastname = $value->lastname;
                    $grade = $value->grade;
                    $email = $value->email;
                    $images = json_decode($value->userfile);
                endforeach;

                $user_info = array(
                    'id' => $user_id,
                    'firstname' => $firstname,
                    'lastname' => $lastname,
                    'grade' => $grade,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'images' => $images[0]->file_name,
                    'is_logged_in' => TRUE
                    );

                $this->session->set_userdata($user_info);

                redirect('Students/homepage');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error! Invalid username or password');
                redirect('Students/login_user');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('signup');
        }
    }
```

**model**
the join here is for a different table in the same db where the common row is id..not sure if the join is correct too

```
public function fetchUserData()
    {
        $this->db->select('users.*, user_images.*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('user_images', 'users.id=user_images.user', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1 ) :
            foreach($query->result() as $row):
                $data[] = $row;
            endforeach;
            return $data;
        endif;
    }
```

**view**  the img scr here should display the user image based on what is saved on the db when he/she first registered

```
</head>

<body>



<h3>Welcome  <?php $this->session->userdata('$firstname')?>.</h3>;
<a href=""> <img class ="img-circle" src="<?=base_url();?>uploads/users/<?=$this->session->userdata('userfile/file_name');?>" width="250" height="auto"></a>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your views. where the session variable should be without the $ symbol. Also echo is not used. It should be like `<?php echo $this->session->userdata('firstname'); ?>`.

Comment: here you get `var_dump($data);` the data ?

Comment: You should use a library like Aauth or Ion-auth instead of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your views. where the session variable should be without the $ symbol.

```
<h3>Welcome  <?php echo $this->session->userdata('firstname'); ?>.</h3>;
```

Also, check if the `$user_info` contains the expected data. Do a `var_dump($user_info)` and see just before creating the session.

Answer (score 0):

there could be many issues with it.
1: your are passing a variable in the string which is not valid  ( $this->session->userdata('$firstname') ) remove the $ from the first name; 
2: there has to be a constructor in the controller so that the session could be called when ever the object is created;
hope it will solve your problem